# Error when configuring install of GHC version 7.6.3 on wsl with Ubuntu: error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.3:

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ghc, gmp

I'm working on a research project that will require the use of software that runs on top of an older version of Haskell and GHC, specifically 7.6.3. I've managed to download the source however whenever I run the configuration script (with any options), I'm left with the following error:

`checking for path to top of build tree... utils/ghc-pwd/dist-install/build/tmp/ghc-pwd: error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory configure: error: cannot determine current directory`

So far, I've tried to install any version of libgmp old enough that it would have a file with that name but I haven't been able to find anything like that that is still available.

I have also attempted to download the binaries for GHC 7.6.3 directly from [https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc/+packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Ehvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc/+packages) (linked from the official GHC site), however I'm unfamiliar with launchpad and couldn't figure out how to use the PPA.

Does anyone have a fool proof way to install legacy versions of GHC on any version of ubuntu for WSL?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to use the official GHC [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ehvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc/+packages?batch=75&memo=75&start=75):

Each GHC build in the PPA has a few associated .deb files, so when you find the one you want and with the correct architecture, simply copy the link address and download the file using wget or curl

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc-staging/+build/16234874/+files/ghc-7.6.3_7.6.3-15~14.04_amd64.deb
curl -kOL https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc-staging/+build/16234874/+files/ghc-7.6.3_7.6.3-15~14.04_amd64.deb
```

Then you can use whatever method you like to install the .deb file. A few different methods are described [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-deb-packages-on-ubuntu/)

Finally, you need to add the binaries to the path, so add the following line to your .bashrc file

```
export PATH="/opt/ghc/bin:$PATH"
```

Hope that helps anyone in the future!